# Bootstrap navbar drop down

Tags: html

i am working with bootstrap and I can't seem to get the navbar with the dropdown to display on the webpage what can I do any suggestions.

below is the code I am using for the navbar

Navbar
        
          
        
        
            
                
                    Home (current)
                
                
                    Features
                
                
                    Pricing
                
                
                    
                Dropdown link
              
                    
                        Action
                        Another action
                        Something else here

Comment: could you please share the code and screenshot?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.